# Methods of adding many (unspecified number) objects form database via Rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to write my own app. It should provide adding food products with parameters, what I was already done , further aim is to sum all property form added products, compare with daily balance, etc.

I have a problem with concept of connecting products to a meal. Im wondering if is some pretty alternative to function with specific number of (optional) parameters, witch is a certain limitation of functionality. Here is a makeshift solution, but I don't like it, so I'm not developing it for now. Is there a better way to do this?

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public Integer adding(@RequestParam("i") Long index,
                      @RequestParam("i2") Long index2,
                      @RequestParam(value="i3", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long index3,
                      @RequestParam(value="i4", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long index4,
                      @RequestParam(value="i5", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long index5,
                      @RequestParam(value="i6", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long index6
){
    Integer sum = null;


   Integer i1 = productManager.findById(index).get().getCalories();
   Products second = productManager.findById(index2).get();
   Integer i2 = second.getCalories();

   Integer i3,a,b,c;
   if (index3==0){
       i3=0;
   } else {
       Products thrid = productManager.findById(index3).get();
       i3 = thrid.getCalories();
   }
    sum= i1+i2+i3;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list as query param.

```java
@RequestMapping("/add")
public Integer adding(@RequestParam("index") List<Long> indicies){...}
```

The URL will be the following: `http://yourhost:port/add?index=1&index=2&index=3`
I suggest to use better name to method and url param then `add`. Maybe `sumCalories` or something like that.

If you use RDBMS to persist your products (can you give me more detail please?), you can write a query to sum the requiered value:

```java
@Query("select sum(p.calorie) from Products p where p.id in :ids")
Long sumCaloriesByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

Comment: Im using Mysql,  javax.persistance, CrudRepository form Spring. You mean to use JPQL as a manager instead of CrudRepository  ?

Comment: you can use crudrepository and on the interface use query annotation like this:


public interface PhoneRepository extends JpaRepository<Phone, String> {

    List<Phone> findByOwnerOrderByImei(Programmer programmer);

    @Query("select p from Phone p where p.imei=?1")
    Phone findByImei(String imei);
}

Notice i use here jparepository as super interface, but you can change it to CrudRepository.

Comment: I was used List, as You said, and in forech i was wrote this line:
sumCal += productManager.findById(id).map(Product::getCalories).orElse(0F));
And that solution satisfied me for a while,
but I realized I need probably hashMap. Every product should be multipled by weight. Can I somehow request Map instead of List ? And then how http request should look like?

Comment: can you give me furher information? 
where the weight comes etc, maybe some code example on pastebin?